# Issues related to ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I've been trying to develop a pay system using the guidance from some video tutorials.
I've done everything as follows and upgrade the version of some dependencies.However, When I try to build this program I got an error:
Issues related to ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver.

Here are my pom.xml  files:

this is parent's pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springCloudLearning</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>cloud-provider-payment8001</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

this is the pom.xml of module

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>springCloudLearning</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>cloud-provider-payment8001</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I thought that may be I mixed different versions, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me ...

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` and find the conflicting versionjs. I suspect either mybatis or the alibaba stuff isn't compatible with Spring Boot 2.6. If you want more help please add the **full** stacktrace as t hat will show the actual culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know why this happened.
I found mybatis-spring-boot-starter and druid-spring-boot-starter rely on the same dependency spring-boot-autoconfigure and their versions conflict with each other.
When I exclude spring-boot-autoconfigure in druid-spring-boot-starter, everything works! Thanks to idea's powerful dependency Diagram[image]